# HIbernate query parameter binding throws QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this hql query :

... DATE_ADD(p.bar.foo, INTERVAL :param SECOND) < NOW() ...

Hibernate throws this exception :

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: : near line 1, column 715
```

Hibernate says that the syntax exception is related to :param.

What i wanted to do is just to bind param in a none hql experssion.

Comment: Could you please provide minimized but complete hql to reproduce your problem. What database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate HQL doesn't have `INTERVAL`.
You can try to use `Criteria` with native SQL using `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()`

https://fmdojo.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/native-sql-inside-criteria-hibernate/